# jsp el logic question

Tags: jsp, jstl, logic, expression

I have something like this..

```
<c:if test="${(not empty students) && (studentID != null)}">
      <form:input path=studentsList[${studentID}].name">
      ..........
      ..........
      //some 50+ lines of code
</c:if>
```

This is when they are viewing particular student's page. If the are viewing some generic page I want to change the code to something like this..

```
 <c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
      <form:input path=student.name">
      ..........
      ..........
      //some 50+ lines of code
</c:forEach>
```

I can have an if statement to check if they are viewing a particular page or generic page

```
 <c:when ${particularPage}>
       <c:if test="${(not empty students) && (studentID != null)}">
            <form:input path=studentsList[${studentID}].name">
            ..........
            ..........
            //some 50+ lines of code
      </c:if>
<c:otherwise>
      <c:forEach items="${students}" var="student">
             <form:input path=student.name">
            ..........
            ..........
            //some 50+ lines of code
      </c:forEach>
</c:otherwise>
```

Can anyone tell me how can we change the code so that I dont have to repeat those 50+ lines??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of a [jsp tag file](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tutorials/jsp20/tagfiles.html) would come in handy here. Simply create a tag (`custom.tag`, for example) that takes the `form:input` path as an attribute:

```
<%@ attribute name="path" required="true" %>
<form:input path="${path}">
//some 50+ lines of code
```

And then use invoke it in your calling jsp:

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="h" %>
...
    <c:when ${particularPage}> 
       <c:if test="${(not empty students) && (studentID != null)}"> 
          <h:custom path="studentsList[${studentID}].name"/>     
       </c:if> 
       <c:otherwise> 
          <c:forEach items="${students}" var="student"> 
              <h:custom path="student.name"/>
          </c:forEach> 
       </c:otherwise> 
    </c:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, but I solved it. I wrote scriplets and solved the problem.

```
<%for(int i = request.getAttribute("studentId") == null ? 0 : ((Integer)request.getAttribute("studentId")).intValue();
 i< ((List)request.getAttribute("students")).size(); i++){

  request.setAttribute("id", new Integer(i));
 %>

  <form:input path=studentsList[${id}].name">
        ..........
        ..........
        //some 50+ lines of code

<% if(!"true".equals(request.getAttribute("specificPage")){break;}
 }
 %>
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this but its working!!!

Please let me know if what I am doing is wrong.

Comment: Scriptlets are a bad way to go. Give another look at btiernay's tag file solution.